# How often should I visit to see whether Tubbs will lounge on the giant cushion?

Tags: neko-atsume

I know this is a long shot asking here, but I having passively been interacting with Neko Atsume for a long time. The only remaining novelty for me is trying to attract Tubbs to a giant cushion. I have implemented [details on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/search?q=tubbs%20cushion&restrict_sr=) about placements of the cushions (tan & white), food combinations (double Frisky Bits or double Ritzy Bits), etc.

My only question is if you've been successful, how often did you visit the app to see if Tubbs enjoyed a giant cushion?